# mgo $unwind aggregation result to Unknown element kind (0x2E)

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

I have an aggregate query like this

`$ db.histories.aggregate([{$match:{"issue_id":{$in:ids},"history_comment":{$exists:true,$not:{$size:0}}}},{$unwind:"$history_comment"}])`

translating this to `go` using `mgo`

```
    var h []History
query := []bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{
        "issue_id":        bson.M{"$in": IDs},
        "history_comment": bson.M{"$exists": true, "$not": bson.M{"$size": 0}}}},
    {"$unwind": "$history_comment"},

}

err := c.Pipe(query).All(&h)
```

but I received an `err`

`Unknown element kind (0x2E)`
how is this possible? is my query wrong?

Comment: While bson trying to decode your data it can't identify "kind" of data. Error is coming from  (d *decoder) readElemTo function  in http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v1/view/head:/bson/decode.go.Your data seems not compatible with any bson types .

Answer (score 1):

The error returned is pointing out that the data being handed to the driver has an unknown element kind. Looking at the BSON specification, there's indeed no `0x2E` element kind in there:

http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

If you think this is an issue in the driver, can you please provide a dump of the offending data that can be loaded into the driver, and open an issue with it?

Thank you.