# Unmarshalling BSON data using Gobson/Mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am receiving different BSON documents, an example seen here:

```
{ "group" : { "id": ObjectId("11a123456bc345d452d32c0b5"), "name": "SomeName" }, "count1": 6, "count2": 33, "totalCount": 39 }
```

I am trying to use mgo/gobson to unmarshal this data into a map[string]interface{}, but keep getting an error.  The unmarshalling code is

```
var record map[string]interface{}

err := bson.Unmarshal(data, &record)
```

This resulted in a error saying the document was corrupted.  Looking into the code I saw that it expected the length of the byte array to be the first few bytes so I added code similar to what is found in the tests.

```
rec := make([]byte, len(data)+6)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(rec, uint32(len(rec)))
copy(rec[4:], data)
```

This got me past the corrupt document error, but now I am getting

```
Unknown element kind (0x7B)
```

What am I doing wrong that I can't easily unmarshal the above BSON document into a map?  Is there a problem with the BSON document itself?  I am not the creator of the BSON document, but am able to provide feedback to them if necessary.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the BSON document, not your code. Where is the document coming from?

Comment: The document is provided by another team.  I am responsible for pulling and ingesting the data into the system that I work with.

Comment: I spoke with the other team and was told that they have a script for querying MongoDB and dumping the results into a file and that is what I am pulling.

Comment: Does your BSON literally look like the human-readable `{ "group" : { "id": ObjectId("11a123456bc345d452d32c0b5"), "name": "SomeName" }, "count1": 6, "count2": 33, "totalCount": 39 }` or is it in binary form?

Comment: If they want to get you BSON, they should be using the mongodump tool. I would double-check with them to make sure. It would be really helpful if you could outline their workflow here.

Comment: They were apparently just issuing queries to MongoDB and dumping the results into a file which as you mention is MongoDB extended JSON.  I have gone to the team and they are now outputting JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out your code above and I managed to get it to "work". The reason you are getting

```
Unknown element kind (0x7B)
```

is because there is no element of kind `0x7B`  in the BSON specification. See here http://bsonspec.org/spec.html. The particular unknow element I was getting was the byte value for the first curly bracket({) in your document

```
{ "group" : { "id": ObjectId("11a123456bc345d452d32c0b5"), "name": "SomeName" }, "count1": 6, "count2": 33, "totalCount": 39 }
```

after tweaking the code a bit I was able to get it working with out the `unknown kind` error.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    bsonData := `{ "group" : { "id": ObjectId("11a123456bc345d452d32c0b5"), "name": "SomeName" }, "count1": 6, "count2": 33, "totalCount": 39 }`

    var record map[string]interface{}

    rec := make([]byte, len(bsonData)+6)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(rec, uint32(len(rec)))
    copy(rec[4:], bsonData)
    //Adding a new line to the front of the rec byte variable seems to do the trick
    r := []byte("\n")
    rec[4] = r[0]
    err := bson.Unmarshal(rec, &record)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(record)
}
```

I also found this answer to be of great use https://stackoverflow.com/a/33129119/2627768

Comment: This does not seem to give the desired effect.  I end up with the whole "bson data" as the key in the map and nil value.

Comment: The string you are using as bsonData above is not valid BSON. It's MongoDB Extended JSON. As the spec explains, BSON is a binary format.